# Is move() with unique_ptr irreplaceable?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, unique-ptr

I am not sure if the title is even relative as I do not have enough knowledge about `move()`. For this very reason it was hard to search and successfully find an answer to my question.

consider the following code:

```
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A(){cout << "Created!\n";}
    ~A(){cout << "Destroyed!\n";};
};

void f()
{
    unique_ptr<A> q(new A);

    unique_ptr<A> t (q.release());  // ----> (1)
    // unique_ptr<A> t = move(q);   // ----> (2) 
}

int main() { f(); }
```

My understanding is: in both cases `(1)` and `(2)` the `t` will take the `A` ownership from `q` without destroying the `object A`.

1. Is this correct?
2. What is the difference between `(1)` and `(2)`?

I can see that `move()` is not part of the `unique_ptr`, instead it seems to me part of `std` so it has more general uses.

I am new to `C++` and so in the simplest possible way:

3. What can move do? What are its uses?

Comment: if `using namespace std;` is necessary to run your code, you should include that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, it is correct.
2. In your case, no visible difference.

Let me elaborate on question 3: *what can move do?*

`std::move`, as you noted, is not part of `unique_ptr` but of `std`. It is able to move any moveable object, not just pointers.

In the particular case of `unique_ptr` there is that handy `release()` that allows you to move the pointer manually, without using the move operators. But think for example of `std::thread` or `std::fstream`, there are no release/reacquire operators there.

Note that `std::move` by itself does nothing. Some people think that it returns a temporary while destroying the original, so a single:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> q(new A);
std::move(q); //this does nothing!!!
```

would move `q` to nothingness and destroy the object...

This is not true. All that `std::move()` does is a cast to an rvalue-reference. It is actually the *move assignment operator* (`operator=(T&&)`) or the *move constructor* (`T(T&&)`) that does the real moving.

You could also say:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> q(new A);
std::unique_ptr<A> r(static_cast<std::unique_ptr<A>&&>(q));
```

but that is cumbersome. `std::move()` is nicer to look at:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> q(new A);
std::unique_ptr<A> r(std::move(q));
```